# TypeScript definition for RequireJS Module return without export

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

**Usage without TypeScript**

I have a RequireJS Module which i can't edit

The RequireJS Module:

```
//app/Router.js
define([], function() {
  return {
    generate: function(route) { /*do something*/ }
  }
});
```

The module don't have any export, but with the return statement it works in other require modules by using it like:

```
define(['app/Router'], function(router) {
  router.generate('myRoute');
});
```

I want to use the app/Router.js in TypeScript

**Variant 1: TypeScript knows the type, but JS has errors**

So i try to make my definition module:

```
//Router.d.ts
export interface Router
{
    generate(route:string): string;
}
declare let router: Router;
export default router;
```

Using it in my TypeScript file like:

```
import router from 'app/Router'

router.generate('something');
```

Will generate that file:

```
define(
  ["require", "exports", "app/Router"], 
  function (require, exports, Router_1)
) {
   Router_1.default.generate();
}
```

The Problem is the default attribute. JS says that can't call generate on null. Because Router_1 is already the object i want.

**Variant 2: JS is correct but TypeScript don't knows the type**

I also tried:

```
//Router.d.ts
export interface Router
{
    generate(route:string): string;
}
declare let router: Router;
declare module "router" {
    export = router;
}
```

Using it like:

```
import * as router from 'app/Router'

router.generate('something');
```

The output is correct:

```
define(["require", "exports", "app/Router"], function (require, exports, router) {
  router.generate();
});
```

But TypeScript compiler says: Property 'generate' does not exist on type

**Question**

How must my Router.d.ts and import statement looks like, in order to have the right output and TypeScript knows the correct type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use *export* *default* *stuff* you are telling to the compiler that the object exported has a property named *default* which has as value *stuff*, if in the .js file the object.default == undefined it will throw a TypeError when invoked as a function. Try this approach instead:

```
//Router.d.ts

declare module "app/Router" { // <- this must contain the path and the file's name;

    const router: { 
        generate: (route: string) => string; 
    }

    export = router;
}

// in the .ts file ...

import * as router from "app/Router";

router.generate("go/some/url");
```

Using tsc 2.6.1 this outputs:

```
define(["require", "exports", "app/Router"], function (require, exports, router) {
                                                               //^^^^^^^
    "use strict";                                              //|||||||      
    exports.__esModule = true; // <- it extends this object that was passed as argument ... 
    router.generate("go/some/url");// <- but this was the desired effect, right?
});
```

I have no prior knowledge of the amd system so i have no way to tell what are the consequences of extending or setting the exports object inside the body of the function. I don't think that the change that was made will matter, but is better check for yourself anyway.

Comment: Before i tried also with declare module "app/Router", but i got error "Exports and export assignments are not permitted in module augmentations". I guess this happens because i defined my interface outside the declare module. Your Code works well. Thanks!